# Logging large strings from Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a Flutter App and learning Dart in the process, but I'm getting kind of frustrated when debugging. I have fetched a resource from an API and now I want to print the JSON string to the console, but it keeps cutting off the string.

[image: Screenshot of the cut off string in the console]

So I actually have two questions: is the terminal console really the only way to print debug messages and how can I print large strings to the console without them automatically getting cut off?

Comment: Why not simply using breakpoints instead ?

Comment: Have you tried if `flutter logs` or `adb logcat` provides full output?

Comment: Breakpoints are a good suggestion, but still, it shouldn't be impossible to just print the whole response JSON string to the console without pausing my app? Breakpoints are great, but not always what you want...

Comment: `flutter logs` displays the same, that's actually where the screenshot comes from.

Comment: Confirmed working by using debugPrint(someSuperLongString, wrapWidth: 1024);

Comment: Have they recently increased the limit for the `print()` command? Coz I just printed a string of over 2,000 lines, each with 81 characters, and it didn't get truncated...

Answer (score 210):

How about using the Flutter log from the `dart: developer` library. This does not seem to have the maximum length limit like `print()` or `debugPrint()`. This is the only solution that seems to work fine. Try it as below:

```
import 'dart:developer';


log(reallyReallyLongText);
```

The output will be the entire long string without breaks and prefixed with `[log]`

Comment: what am I doing wrong ?     var data = {
      'recordType':recordTypeText,
      'horseId': horseId,
      'dateOfCheck': dateOfCheck,
      'title': title,
      'details': details,
      'images':images
    };

log(data.toString()); and no output

Comment: doesn't work for me still getting trucated

Comment: @user1634451 its a different level of output, you might not see it on the terminal but it works on vscode

Comment: it works!!!.. any probs importing the developer import ?

Comment: @sisir Seems to log only work when the device is connected to the system to check the logs. As soon as you disconnect it will not show the log. Download APK and want to check the log of the app for testing purposes. Any help here?

Comment: I am still seeing no output in terminal in my VSCODE, I don't understand why there are so many upvote , or in latest version this log is not working? or anyone please state more specific steps on how to check the printed value? There are tabs like "Terminal" , "OUTPUT" , "DEBUG CONSOLE" , "PROBLEMS"  , should I find it in OUTPUT or how?

Comment: @elliotching same. Doesn't log anything terminal or debugconsole(vscode). debugPrint did it(see further)

Comment: @kustekjé-meklootn , I found we need to press v in terminal and it open chrome inspector , the log will be inside "Logging" section, however, still there are lots of Logging data string failed to load/read/retrieve, it shows loading spinner forever if the text is too long

Answer (score 76):

You can make your own print. Define this method

```
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

Use it like

```
printWrapped("Your very long string ...");
```

[Credit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665#issuecomment-458186456)

Answer (score 26):

Use debugPrint with the optional parameter to wrap according to the platform's output limit.

```
debugPrint(someSuperLongString, wrapWidth: 1024);
```

Comment: it prints everything but again result is being truncated...

Comment: What do you mean, Jan? :-? If it still truncates, how does it "print everything"?

Comment: It splits the log on console, but still doesn't print the large log completely!

Answer (score 18):

Currently dart doesn't support printing logs more than 1020 characters (found that out by trying).

So, I came up with this method to print long logs:

```
static void LogPrint(Object object) async {
    int defaultPrintLength = 1020;
    if (object == null || object.toString().length <= defaultPrintLength) {
       print(object);
    } else {
       String log = object.toString();
       int start = 0;
       int endIndex = defaultPrintLength;
       int logLength = log.length;
       int tmpLogLength = log.length;
       while (endIndex < logLength) {
          print(log.substring(start, endIndex));
          endIndex += defaultPrintLength;
          start += defaultPrintLength;
          tmpLogLength -= defaultPrintLength;
       }
       if (tmpLogLength > 0) {
          print(log.substring(start, logLength));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1023 actually. That's 1 KB - 1 character. :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a one-liner based on [@CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618622/copsonroad)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57579005/6045800) that you can quickly copy and paste (such as: when you want to slightly modify your code and log some data and see temporarily):

```
void printWrapped(String text) => RegExp('.{1,800}').allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0)).forEach(print);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try `debugPrint('your output');` instead of `print('your output');` the documentation is [here](https://flutter.io/debugging/#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs) if you would like to read. `debugPrint` throttles the output to a level to avoid being dropped by android's kernel as per the documentation.

Comment: I also read that and I did try `debugPrint` to no avail. I'm also running my app on the iPhone simulator right now, and there's nothing about logs being cut off when developing for iOS.

Comment: hmm, thanks for letting me know about this. I will try and check once again and run it on iosSimulator.

Comment: debugPrint() also truncates long strings for me. Limited seems to be 700 characters.

Comment: Yes me also still got truncated using debugprint

Comment: just need to add `wrapWidth: <SomeBigInt>` calling debugPrint and it will not truncate

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue for that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665

debugPrint and print are actually truncating the output.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the [Logger Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/logger): https://pub.dev/packages/logger

To print any type of log Just do the do the following.

```
  var logger = Logger();

  logger.d("Logger is working!");// It also accept json objects
```

In fact, it will even format the output for you.

Comment: It's still not working for me :/

Comment: Didn't Work for me

Comment: still get truncate. Didn't work

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Flutter DevTools**. It has a **Logging View** section with logs containing full string.

https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/logging

Answer (score 3):

I have the perfect solution,It can be parsed no matter how long it is, and it is still in json format, Can be easily parsed or copied for use

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:convert';
...
...
log('${jsonEncode(responseData)}');
```

Answer (score 1):

> Method 1

```
   void prints(var s1) {
        String s = s1.toString();
        debugPrint(" =======> " + s, wrapWidth: 1024);
      }
```

> Method 2

```
void prints(var s1) {
  String s = s1.toString();
  final pattern = RegExp('.{1,800}');
  pattern.allMatches(s).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

Just call this method to print your `longggg string`

Answer (score -1):

If you run the application in android studio it will truncate long string.

In xcode 10.2 which i am using long string is not truncating.

My suggestion is write print statement logs and run the application in Xcode instead of android studio.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue caused lot of frustration when I have to test **base64** of images.
I was using **iTerm2 editor**, so the answer is specific to the iTerm2

```
 1. Navigate to Preferences -> Profiles
 2. Select your Profile (in my case was **Default** only)
 3. Select **Terminal** in the header of right pan
 4. Check Unlimited scrollback
```

Now you can have copy the large strings from the terminal.

Comment: where is this option in android studio ?

Comment: The above answer is specific to iTerm2.

For Android studio, you can do so from:
Settings -> Tools -> Logcat -> Logcat cycle buffer size

Comment: there is no logcat inside tools

Comment: Please follow this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#addl-config-options

Comment: @VipinVerma, double-check if you are looking for Tools inside Settings of the Android Studio, it shouldn't be the one in the toolbar.