# Is there a way to print a console message with Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm debugging an app, but I need to know some values in the fly, I was wondering if there's a way to print a message in console like console.log using Javascript.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`print()` is probably what you are looking for. [Here's](https://flutter.io/debugging/#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs) some more info on debugging in flutter.

Comment: is print bad to have in production app aswell or is it fine to leave the prints for real app?

Comment: @Mattias I personally would not recommend having print/debug statements in a production app... (if you have rampant print/debug statements, it will affect the performance of the app --- even if it is a minuscule impact).

Comment: Is there any way where we can write `array [0]`, `array[1]` or any run time assignment in the debugger ?

Comment: If I want to print things in terminal instead of IDE console. Which method I could use?

Comment: Flutter has added a the linter [avoid_print](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_print.html) suggesting the removal of print statements from production code. Check out `log` in `'dart:developer'` or `debugPrint`

Answer (score 36):

There are more helpful methods in `import 'dart:developer'` library and one of them is **`log()`**.

example:

```
int i = 5;
log("Index number is: $i");

//output
[log] Index number is: 5
```

> void log(String message, {DateTime time, int sequenceNumber, int level
>   = 0, String name = '', Zone zone, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace})
>
> Emit a log event.
>
> This function was designed to map closely to the logging information
>   collected by package:logging.
>
> ```
> [message] is the log message
> [time] (optional) is the timestamp
> [sequenceNumber] (optional) is a monotonically increasing sequence number
> [level] (optional) is the severity level (a value between 0 and 2000); see the package:logging Level class for an overview of the
> ```
>
> possible values
>       [name] (optional) is the name of the source of the log message
>       [zone] (optional) the zone where the log was emitted
>       [error] (optional) an error object associated with this log event
>       [stackTrace] (optional) a stack trace associated with this log event

[Read more.](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-developer/dart-developer-library.html):

`print()` is from dart:core and its implementation:

```
/// Prints a string representation of the object to the console.
void print(Object object) {
  String line = "$object";
  if (printToZone == null) {
    printToConsole(line);
  } else {
    printToZone(line);
  }
}
```

`debugPrint()`:

```
/// Prints a message to the console, which you can access using the "flutter"
/// tool's "logs" command ("flutter logs").
///
/// If a wrapWidth is provided, each line of the message is word-wrapped to that
/// width. (Lines may be separated by newline characters, as in '\n'.)
///
/// By default, this function very crudely attempts to throttle the rate at
/// which messages are sent to avoid data loss on Android. This means that
/// interleaving calls to this function (directly or indirectly via, e.g.,
/// [debugDumpRenderTree] or [debugDumpApp]) and to the Dart [print] method can
/// result in out-of-order messages in the logs

// read more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html
DebugPrintCallback debugPrint = debugPrintThrottled;


/// Alternative implementation of [debugPrint] that does not throttle.
/// Used by tests. 
debugPrintSynchronously(String message, { int wrapWidth })

/// Implementation of [debugPrint] that throttles messages. This avoids dropping
/// messages on platforms that rate-limit their logging (for example, Android).
void debugPrintThrottled(String message, { int wrapWidth })
```

[Read more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html).

Note that only the `print()` is taking any type and print to the console. `debugPrint()` and `log()` only take `String`. So, you have to add `.toString()` or use string interpolation like I shown in provided example snippet.

Comment: log() is the only one of those that shows me the whole result of a JSON, thanks.

Answer (score 28):

You can use

```
print()
```

function or

```
debugPrint()
```

The debugPrint() function can print large outputs.

Comment: Requires `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` for me.

Answer (score 10):

I tend to do something similar to this

```
Foo foo;
try{
    foo = _someMethod(); //some method that returns a new object
} catch (e) {
    print('_someMethod: Foo Error ${foo.id} Error:{e.toString()}'); /*my custom error print message. You don't need brackets if you are printing a string variable.*/
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use debug print to avoid logging in production application.

```
debugPrint("Message");
```

You can also disable or change debug print implementation in main.dart or any other file like this:

```
debugPrint = (String message, {int wrapWidth}) 
{
    debugPrintThrottled(message);//Or another other custom code
};
```

Answer (score 6):

**`print`, `debugPrint` and others have got some word limit restrictions**, if you have something long to print on console, you can:

Create this method:

```
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

Usage:

```
printWrapped("Your very long string ...");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57579005/6618622)

Answer (score 5):

```
debugPrint()
```

Might as well use rather than `print()` as it attempts to reduce log line drop or being out of order on Android kernel

Refs:

[Logging in Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html)

Answer (score 4):

One more answer for Concatenate with String:

```
// Declaration
int number = 10;


//Button Action
RaisedButton(
child: Text("Subtract Me"),
onPressed: () {
      number = number - 1;
      print('You have got $number as result');
      print('Before Value is ${number - 1} and After value is ${number + 1}');
    },
),

//Output:
flutter: You have got 9 as result
flutter: Before Value is 8 and After value is 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this. The print() function can print data up to some limit. So I use this log.

```
    import 'dart:developer';
    
    debugLog({String tag = '', required dynamic value}) {
      log("TAG $tag : ${value.toString()}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you, because, I was also got stuck in many ways of knowing the output of my code in the dart file, hence I got the solution by following the steps, shown in the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhP1tE-IHos

here I have shown an instance of how it works after following the video.
check the left side column where it shows about the value which **profile** variable carry i.e., **null**
[image: Dart dev tools working]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28067865)

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback I will edit my response. and I will try to give some helpful suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `print('whatever you want to print')` same as `console.log()` in javascript.

for more info you can [check here](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `print()` and `log()` options both add their own labels at the start of the line, and apply additional formatting that can cause long lines to be truncated. In the case of a `dart:io` app, you can bypass this interception and mangling entirely by going directly to stdout/stderr, etc. as in `stdout.write()`, `stdout.writeln()`, etc. Likewise if you are looking to log explicitly to one or the other. I ran into this issue when adding CLI args to a flutter application.