# Flutter reads JSON just partially

Tags: flutter, dart, bundle

I'm using Flutter / Dart to create a little app, and it works quite fine. My assets are correctly defined in `pubspec.yaml`.

However, when I try to load data from assets (JSON) it only loads half of the data.

`appData.json`

```
{
"plan": [
    {
        "name": "plan_demo",
        "author": "A Name",
        "version": 1,
        "times_completed": 0,
        "percent_done": 0,
        "last_date_read": "1970-01-09",
        "missedDate": [
            {
                "date": "1970-01-01"
            },
            {
                "date": "1970-01-05"
            }
        ],
        "part": [
            {
                "isDone": false,
                "startBook": 1,
                "endBook": 1,
                "startChapter": 1,
                "endChapter": 1,
                "startVerse": 1,
                "endVerse": 5
            },
            {
                "isDone": false,
                "startBook": 1,
                "endBook": 1,
                "startChapter": 1,
                "endChapter": 1,
                "startVerse": 6,
                "endVerse": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "another plan",
        "author": "Another Name",
        "version": 1,
        "times_completed": 0,
        "percent_done": 0,
        "last_date_read": "2020-12-28",
        "missedDate": [
            {
                "date": "2020-11-01"
            }
        ],
        "part": [
            {
                "isDone": false,
                "startBook": 1,
                "endBook": 1,
                "startChapter": 1,
                "endChapter": 1,
                "startVerse": 1,
                "endVerse": 5
            },
            {
                "isDone": false,
                "startBook": 1,
                "endBook": 1,
                "startChapter": 1,
                "endChapter": 1,
                "startVerse": 6,
                "endVerse": 10
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The calling method looks like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  rootBundle.loadString("assets/appData.json").then((value) {
    print('rootBundle : ' + value);
  });
}
```

The output now is:

```
I/flutter (20595): rootBundle : {
I/flutter (20595):     "plan": [
I/flutter (20595):         {
I/flutter (20595):             "name": "plan_demo",
I/flutter (20595):             "author": "A Name",
I/flutter (20595):             "version": 1,
I/flutter (20595):             "times_completed": 0,
I/flutter (20595):             "percent_done": 0,
I/flutter (20595):             "last_date_read": "1970-01-09",
I/flutter (20595):             "missedDate": [
I/flutter (20595):                 {
I/flutter (20595):                     "date": "1970-01-01"
I/flutter (20595):                 },
I/flutter (20595):                 {
I/flutter (20595):                     "date": "1970-01-05"
I/flutter (20595):                 }
I/flutter (20595):             ],
I/flutter (20595):             "part": [
I/flutter (20595):                 {
I/flutter (20595):                     "isDone": false,
I/flutter (20595):                     "startBook": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "endBook": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "startChapter": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "endChapter": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "startVerse": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "endVerse": 5
I/flutter (20595):                 },
I/flutter (20595):                 {
I/flutter (20595):                     "isDone": false,
I/flutter (20595):                     "startBook": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "endBook": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "startChapter": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "endChapter": 1,
I/flutter (20595):                     "startVerse":
```

Why is my data cut off after some point in the file?

Comment: The print statement only prints a certain number of characters...so your data is probably fine. Try storing your json in a suitable variable and printing its parts.

Comment: Kinda true; when running on virtual Android device, data is fine but cut from the print command. When running in Edge the print command outputs all data. That's kinda strange for me.

Comment: See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665 and other s

Comment: If your json was 1m characters long, not sure you would want to print it all though. So far, I have been pretty happy with print() truncating. :-) If I need more I typically use a class to define it and print exactly the bits I need to see.

Answer (score 1):

Following the link(s) from @GrahamD a possible solution is using

```
debugPrint(someSuperLongString, wrapWidth: 1024);
```

With the optional argument the output is not truncated. With the normal print function truncation happens, even though editors don't show that like in my case.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other answers, the problem is the truncation in the print statement. A lot of methods where discussed to overcome this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138971/logging-large-strings-from-flutter) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665). But I would like to propose a different approach for your case, we can use `inspect()` by importing it from `dart:developer`. This adds folding and works similar to printing an object in the console of the browser. [Link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-developer/inspect.html)

**Example**

```
rootBundle.loadString("assets/appData.json").then((value) {
  inspect(jsonDecode(value));
});
```

This works well in this case as it is more practical to use folding over printing the entire JSON as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly nicer workaround might be to create your own `print` that `splits` into *smaller chunks*, then you don't need to modify the `code` for each long `string`. Eg.:

```
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

Use it like

```
printWrapped("Your very long string ...");
```

[Credits](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665#issuecomment-458186456) *and For More Solution to print a Long String in flutter* [See This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138971/logging-large-strings-from-flutter) *Thread*